# Are there any natural outdoor ice skating locations in Australia?

Tags: australia, winter, outdoor-activities, winter-sports

I know winter is over now but it likely will be winter again by the time I get back to Australia.

I also know there are a few temporary outdoor ice skating rinks but I do not know if there is any non artificial place such as a lake that freezes over in Australia in the winter.

Obviously it could't happen in any of the cities but what about up in any of the destinations where there are ski resorts like Bulla, Hotham, etc? What about as a specific adventure to whatever is the highest altitude lake in the country?

Comment: I found some mentions of a Lake Catani, where skating used to be popular in the early part of the previous century but that it hasn't been possible to skate on for 50 years now.

Comment: Yes on falls creek their is a massive lake as well as on too

Comment: Could you share the last time you saw people skating on it, perhaps with photos if you have any?

Comment: 'Natural ice' to skate on in countries that do not get cold enough to have big lakes freeze over is mostly very shallow water. In mountains shallow big enough ponds are rare. An other option often used is a level field put under a thin layer of water, which again is hard in mountains. A third, not really natural ice, is to spray an area with a mist of water while it is freezing, this can be grass but hard surfaces do give better results. Not the thing you look for. (So no answer, just a comment.)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is a lake that could freeze over. A few mountain regions in VIC, TAS NSW and even SA get snow during winter, but there aren't any lakes at this attitude. The coldest place in Australia I could find was Collinsvale, TAS (close to Hobart) with a minimum average temp of +7.5 degree C. This is still pretty far away from cold enough for lakes to freeze over, and news sites already post pictures if [snow turns into ice](http://www.abcscience.com.au/news/2010-06-16/snow-turns-to-ice/869878) there. You need a few days of minus temperatures before a lake freezes over and the ice is thick enough to carry humans.

But I was surprised when I found frost on the windshield of my car one cold morning in Perth, WA.

Comment: I thought you might be right since I don't know much about the physics of freezing lakes, but then I found [this page about ice climbing at Mount Kosciuszko!](http://www.chockstone.org/Gallery/BlueLakePics.htm)